# Why does `False in pandas.Series([True,True])` return True?

Tags: python, pandas

```
False in [True,True]

False in pd.Series([True,True])
```

the first line of code returns False
the second line of code returns True!

I think I must be doing something wrong or missing something here. I get the same thing when I check if the series has 0. Can someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 9):

You are checking whether `0` (internal `False` representation) is in the Series's **index** - [@Uriel has shown a docstring explaining why is it happening](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42684247/5741205):

```
In [286]: False in pd.Series([True,True])
Out[286]: True
```

is the same as:

```
In [287]: 0 in pd.Series([True,True])
Out[287]: True
```

and

```
In [288]: True in pd.Series([True,True])
Out[288]: True
```

is the same as:

```
In [290]: 1 in pd.Series([True,True])
Out[290]: True
```

but

```
In [291]: 2 in pd.Series([True,True])
Out[291]: False
```

because there is no such index in this series:

```
In [292]: pd.Series([True,True])
Out[292]:
0    True
1    True
dtype: bool
```

**UPDATE:**

if you want to check whether at least one series element is False or True:

```
In [296]: (pd.Series([True, True]) == False).any()
Out[296]: False

In [297]: (pd.Series([True, True]) == True).any()
Out[297]: True
```

Comment: sounds reasonable, but how do i know if python compares the first operator with index or value, or python just search it in both set?

Comment: @mxdev, most probably you are looking for something like: `(s == False).any()` where `s` is your series containing `True` or `False` values

Comment: Or just `pd.Series([True, True]).any()` and `(~pd.Series([True, True])).any()` :)

Comment: @Mitch, yes, that's correct, thank you! I also wanted first to use this simplified version, but I decided to use an explicit version as it shows how it works and it'll also work for non-boolean values

Comment: i just did a test to search a string within a string series, it looks like it only search in index/aix

Comment: @MaxU I agree with your reasoning!

Comment: @mxdev, it depends on how do you do that... Try to use the same approach as i used in the UPDATE section...

Comment: @MaxU, thank you so much, it works, and i just got a little confused by the oversimpled syntax. i definitely need more time to study it more thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> help(pd.Series([True, True]).__contains__)
Help on method __contains__ in module pandas.core.generic:

__contains__(key) method of pandas.core.series.Series instance
    True if the key is in the info axis

>>> pd.Series([True, True])
0    True
1    True
dtype: bool

^
info axis
```

Comment: for x in pd.Series(['cd','ab']):
     print x# it will print cd and ab

Comment: @mxdev `list(dict(pd.Series(['cd', 'ab'])))` think dictionaries (**`keys`**), not lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking for more than one value, I highly recommend the [`isin` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html).

```
>>> pd.Series(range(10)).isin([1]).any()
True
```